# Why is my input parameter being modified in this code snippet?

Tags: javascript

Why is my input parameter `inArr` being modified when I update local variable `arr` in the JavaScript code below?

```js
function test(inArr) {
    var arr = inArr;

    for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        arr.push(i);
        console.log( "arr = ", arr, "inArr = ", inArr );
    }
}

test([]);
```

This outputs:

```
arr =  [ 0 ] inArr =  [ 0 ]
arr =  [ 0, 1 ] inArr =  [ 0, 1 ]
arr =  [ 0, 1, 2 ] inArr =  [ 0, 1, 2 ]
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000/is-javascript-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language

Comment: Duplicate of: [Copy array by value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7486085/copy-array-by-value)

Comment: Arrays are objects in Javascript and objects are always passed by reference in JavaScript, also in PHP for example.

Comment: Sorry all for the duplicate question, but sometimes you need to know the answer to the question in order to search for the answer ... thanks gain ...

Comment: @HeatfanJohn Yeah, sometimes the challenge is in knowing just *what* to search for.  No apology is necessary.  We've all been there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript arrays are assigned by reference, so when you make your assignment, both variables are pointing to the same array in memory. Any change to one will also change the other.

You can create a new array with those values using the spread operator:

```
var arr = [...inArray];
```

Comment: How can you post an answer on a closed question. I can't do that and i have 22k more rep :-S

Comment: Most likely I added the answer just before it was closed.

Comment: No, you added it afterwards (3-4 minutes later). I see, there is a serverside grace period which allows posting even if the question got closed. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91922/how-was-this-answer-posted-after-this-question-was-closed

Comment: That makes sense. I answered it from my phone, which doesn't have the same client-side restriction.

Answer (score 1):

because they are the same.

```
function test(inArr) {
    var arr = [].concat(inArr);

    for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        arr.push(i);
        console.log( "arr = ", arr, "inArr = ", inArr );
    }
}

test([]);
```